# How to delete entity with Version annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity with `@Version` annotation. The input to DataManager is entity id and entity version.

```
void deleteEntity(int id, int version) {
  MyEntity entity = entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, id);
  entity.setVersion(version);
  entityManager.remove(entity);
}
```

Using this code the entity is removed even if the version is not correct. Is there any way to verify the version without using JPQL/Criteria?

Comment: How you try entity removal without version setting ???

Comment: @WundwinBorn I don't understand. Could you please rephrase your question?

Comment: What are you trying to do? @Version is used in optimistic locking to check if entity was not modified by different transaction. Version column should not be updated by application manually.

Comment: The version is transmitted to client using web service and should be present in any modification requests to verify client operates on the latest version. According to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking this is should be proper solution: "The object's version attribute is automatically updated by the JPA provider, and should not normally be modified by the application. The one exception is if the application reads the object in one transaction, sends the object to a client, and updates/merges the object in another transaction."

Comment: Hmm.. I'm looking at JSR 317: JPA 2.0 spec and only exception mentioned is bulk update.

Comment: So apparently the wikibooks I posted, which is also the first result in Google for "jpa optimistic locking", is not a reliable source. Any hints on how to implement long-time optimistic locks(the ones that cover the whole user interaction)?

Comment: Are you speaking about transaction ?

Comment: This could be a bug in Hibernate as it should respect the version when removing entities.  Check the SQL being used in the delete SQl to see if it includes the version field and if so, why it might be different.  You might try creating an instance with only the ID and version set, then use merge instead of find.  This should cause an optimistic if the versions don't match